# Man in the Middle (MITM) proxy with HTTPS support

Tags: ruby, https, proxy, man-in-the-middle

We seem to be going round in circles a bit at the moment. We are looking for simple light weight, preferably ruby based proxy that enables us to do the following.

- Proxy HTTPS requests between a browser and a Web app. e.g. GMail
- Intercept and modify the request/responses - Man in the Middle modification
- Generate on the fly SSL certs (or maybe us pre-configured) for use between the proxy and the browser

Using Ruby, we've experimented with [em-proxy](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-proxy) and [Goliath](http://postrank-labs.github.com/goliath/) but I don't think these are quite the right fit.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Best Regards,

Carlskii.

Comment: This thread is a little bit old, but I'm also searching for a https proxy implemented in Ruby (I need it in ruby). So do you have a solution or any hints?

Comment: See also http://alternativeto.net/software/mitmproxy/

Answer (score 13):

There is also [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) written in Python.

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can do this, although it's not Ruby-based.

Answer (score 2):

There is also nice looking multiplatform http://www.charlesproxy.com/ with SSL support. It's in java/native code. It's closed-source paid app with free trail.

Comment: I use this regularly for interrogating mobile app traffic. Just create your own CA and accept it on your device.

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/odcinek/mallory it is more recent though not as fully mature as the previously mentioned other language proxies, this one however IS written in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative.

[Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/download.html), freemium, closed source written in java.

> Burp Proxy is an interactive HTTP/S proxy server for attacking and
>   testing web applications. It operates as a man-in-the-middle between
>   the end browser and the target web server, and allows the user to
>   intercept, inspect and modify the raw traffic passing in both
>   directions.
>
> Burp Proxy allows you to find and exploit application vulnerabilities
>   by monitoring and manipulating critical parameters and other data
>   transmitted by the application. By modifying browser requests in
>   various malicious ways, Burp Proxy can be used to perform attacks such
>   as SQL injection, cookie subversion, privilege escalation, session
>   hijacking, directory traversal and buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy open-source, well-known solution written in java, can be configured on-the-fly using REST API or Java API